# UIImage - Infinite Scrolling Background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview

Does anyone know how to do something like that?
I would like to get a continuous scrolling of the image.

Example: https://vimeo.com/262632459

Comment: you can FSPagerView library for that and set timer for scrolling

Comment: I do not mean slider

Comment: so what do you want to do?

Comment: I have one picture and I want it to be scrolled as a moving background

Comment: but how ? you have a collectionview or tableview with its scrolling you have to scroll imageview like that? or you have just like moving imageview in background just like collectionview cell scroll horizontal?. Please clear your question with more description

Comment: example : https://streamable.com/pneyb

Comment: example link dead,. Attach screenshot/code or something

Comment: https://vimeo.com/262632459

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way of doing it.

**Set it up**

- Create the image you want to scroll in the background. You need to make it minimum as wide as the widest screen you want to support.
- Place two instances of the image you created next to each other inside a regular `UIView`.
- Place the view on the screen with the x position at 0.

**Animate**

- Animate **the view** repeatedly forever, moving the x position from 0 to -width. The width is the width of your **image** (just the width of one instance). Note that since you want to pull the view left, you must pull x in the *negative* direction.

The image will now slide left until the second instance x is at 0. At this position the animation will start over, moving the view one whole image size to the left. This movement will not be noticeable since you use two identical images.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use scrollview or subclass of scrollview and in that scrollview add your image you want to scroll.

override scrollViewDidScroll delegate method of scrollview, here you can control the animation (how much user can scroll or other behaviours)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619392-scrollviewdidscroll?language=objc

And if you want circular image(when image reach to last start again) add two copy of same image, One at zero position, before your acutal image and one at last position after actual image and as soon as image reaches to last remove the font image and add in the last, and if user scrolling in right direction remove the last image and add in front.

In scrollview add three imageview and keep adding and removing from the front and last based on the scroll direction. In scrollViewDidScroll you will get direction of scoll based on change in x value